# The listener of a checkbox doesn't work with a button

Tags: java, jcheckbox

(I'm not native english speaker, but I'll try my best)

Hi, I have a problem with a jcheckbox, I created this using this code

```
try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cuentas ")) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    cmb[i] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
                    cmb[i].setLabel(rs.getObject("cuentascol").toString());
                    jPanel15.add(cmb[i]);
                    cmb[i].setBounds(20, 20 + (i * 20), 160 + (i * 20), 23 + (i * 20));
                    cmb[i].addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
                            JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)evt.getItem();
                        }
                    });
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
```

and I found how to add them a listener, but the listener only works when the button is selected or not by clicking them, and I need to check if this is selected but when i press a button, the button take a number from this

```
int comboNum=1;
                    for(int pp=0;pp<total_checkbox;pp++){

                        comboNum=comboNum+1;
                    }
```

Is in this button where i need to check if the jcheckbox is selected

Answer (score 1):

Because you are creating an [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) and override the [`itemStateChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent)) method.

The doc specify

> Invoked when an item has been selected or deselected by the user.

Which explain why it is not called when you simply click.

You might want to use a [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) instead and override the method [`stateChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html#stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent)).

> Invoked when the target of the listener has changed its state.

Check [this sample](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJCheckBoxEventswithaChangeListenerlistentoarmedpressedselectedorreleasedstate.htm) for how to detect different event like press, selected etc.

Comment: i changed, but in the button in the top of my code this still the same, or how can i check if this works? thanks a lot